# Is there a way to know how much memory is used by a certain function in java?

Tags: java, performance, memory

I am doing a perform analysis of a transformation algorithm with big files. I would like to know if it possible to calculate the memory size a function requires for the different files I'm using.

Comment: There is no straight-forward way calculate memory size of function. You need to take heap dump and analyze in heap dump analyzer such Eclipse MAT plugin. You can also use JMC. Here is example of detecting memory leak, which can give you some pointers - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks001.html

Answer (score 0):

It is problematic in Java to know peak memory needs for a given program, let alone a function, due to the garbage collector being lazy and letting the program grow to the maximum available memory before kicking in and collecting garbage. Due to this it's hard to distinguish how much garbage a program generates vs. how much memory a program actually needs at a minimum.

A low-tech method we used before was to isolate the function in question into a separate program with a `main` method and run it with different `-Xmx` values, starting from say `256m` and reducing the value by half (so 128, 64, 32, ...) until the program throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. In most cases you reach it within a dozen of invocations, giving an accuracy range of a few MB (to learn the baseline JVM needs, repeat the steps with a simple "hello-world" program and subtract the figure). You can even backtrack and incrementally increase the value to learn the required value with an even greater accuracy, though generally a ballpark figure is sufficient.